# How to find the limit of a piecewise function that includes a "otherwise"?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to see if the limit of the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $0$.

$$y_n=\left\{ \begin{align}
1 & \textrm{ if } n \textrm{ is divisible by } 500 \\
\tfrac{1}{n} & \textrm{ otherwise }
\end{align} \right.$$

I want to say no it does not because it either will converge to $1$ or $0$. What is throwing me off is how to verify this by showing work. I understand how to do piece wise functions when given conditions such as $x \leq 5$ and $x>5$ (for example). I do not know how to explain or go about solving this with "otherwise".

Help?

Comment: What definition of limit are you familiar with? Is it in terms of $\epsilon,N$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what it means, by definition, for $y_n$ to approach $0$: for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies |y_n - 0| < \varepsilon.$$
The negation of this is, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that, for all $N \in \Bbb{N}$, there exists some $n \ge N$ such that
$$n \ge N \text{ and } |y_n - 0| \ge \varepsilon.$$
That is, we should be able to nominate some $\varepsilon > 0$ so that the sequence terms fail to eventually stay within $\varepsilon$-distance from $0$.

The problem with this sequence is that it takes the value $1$ infinitely often. If we want to force the sequence to stay within, say, distance $0.1$ of $0$, we can't, because every now and again, it goes to a number distance $1$ away. So, with this in mind, I think we should choose $\varepsilon = 0.1$.

Now, when does $y_n = 1$ specifically? When $n$ is divisible by $500$. If we take some $N$, then we can always find a value of $n \ge N$ such that $500$ divides $n$ (take the ceiling of $n/500$, and multiply that by $500$). So, given any $N$, we can find $n \ge N$ such that $y_n = 1$. For such $n$, we have
$$n \ge N \text{ and } |y_n - 0| = |1 - 0| = 1 \ge 0.1$$
as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence converges to a limit then all of its subsequences converge to the same limit. Consider the subsequence of multiples of $500$ and odd multiples of $250$, and you are done !